# How can I execute a batch file before a program starts?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to find a way to execute a batch file before a program starts. My situation is when I start my program. The programs save files need to be backed up to a separate location.

The backup needs to happen first then the program needs to start all with click one icon.

I have tested the backup batch file and it only takes about 3 seconds to backup the files so the delay does not have to be long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a batch file that first runs the backup and then executes the actual program?  You can then create a short cut to this batch script.  Double clicking on it will run the backup and then the application just as you are looking to do!